# Design pattern to distinguish call as Web Service vs. Local

Tags: web-services, design-patterns

I have to come up with a design for service lookup i.e. decide on whether the service request can be handled locally or should be sent to a remote server (using SOAP Web Service calls). The first thing that comes to my mind is Service Locator.

Are there any other design patterns that fit the requirement? Any pointers or sample code would be helpful?

Comment: Are yu sure you need to do this? Why? What's the exact requirement?

Comment: Yes John I do. Say you have 3 components A,B,C. The architecture is such that all three can be on one machine or A can be on machine 1, B can be on machine 2, C can be on machine 3. Or AB on machine 1 and C on Machine 2. Any combination.

Comment: My bad for somehow assuming you were using .NET and WCF, in which case, this would be a matter of configuration, and not of programming.

Answer (score 0):

Service locator + Factory is exactly what you need. 
The code , in my humble opinion, should look like this:

```
public enum ServiceOrigin {
  REMOTE,LOCAL;
}


public class ServiceLocatorFactory {
   MyService getService(ServiceOrigin origin) {
      ///Return a proper service instance
   }
}


public interface MyService {
   void doSomething();
}



ServiceLocatorFactory factory = //Get the factory somehow
MyService service = factory.getService(ServiceOrigin.REMOTE);
service.doSomething();
```

Comment: I can't capture the LOCAL or REMOTE in my code. I have to check if the service component exists on local machine if it does not then do a lookup.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Dependency Injection. If clients are unaware of where service are located (whether locally or remote), they should depends on abstractions:

```
public interface MyService {
   void doSomething();
}

public class MyClientThatUsesMyService {

  private MyService _service;
  public MyClientThatUsesMyService(MyService service) {
     _service = service;
  }

  public void Go() { _service.doSomething(); }

}
```

Then you can use a Dependency Injection container or (Poor Man's DI) to configure your **composition root** and set lifetime of the objects.